# Getting parameters from URL in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis

In a Zend application with an example url like this one:

```
http://example.com/profile/423423(some id)
```

How do I get param from url?

I try to use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('action');
```

But I get action does not exist.

then I try something like this:

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('profile/:catid', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('profile/:catid',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'profile',
            'action' => 'index' // Check your action and controller
         )));
}
```

How do I get param from url?.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('profile');
```

from your controller.

You shouldn't need to use a custom route.

Kind regards

Garry

EDIT

I have just noticed that you wish to use the profile controller.  The simplest solution would be to add an id into your url like.

http://example.com/profile/id/423423

and get the profile id with

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getParam() methods to retrieve request variables like route, GET and POST.

Inside your controllers action you can do this.

```
$this->getParam('parameterName'); or $this->getRequest()->getParam('parameterName');
```

If you want to get the name of action and controller that matched the current route you need to use following methods.

```
$this->getRequest()->getActionName() and $this->getRequest()->getControllerName()
```